# Как в Docker добавить параметр в mysql.ini?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Всем привет.

Мне нужно добавить в Docker контейнер, который является контейнером для MySQL, атрибут, который меняет mysql.ini файл. А конкретно мне нужно добавить

```
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
```

Я так понимаю нужно что-то поменять в docker-compose.yml.

Подскажите что именно нужно дописать?

Comment: просто создать файл и примонтировать его, в стандартном образе даже есть специальная директория для этого, /etc/mysql/conf.d или как-то так

Comment: @etki Мне не нужно полностью менять весь файл, мне нужно только добавить один атрибут

Comment: Я как раз и добавил ремарку про директорию к тому, что основной конфиг переписывать не надо. У меня сейчас такая строчка в volumes успешно работает `- ./resources/development/mysql-overrides.docker.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/development-overrides.cnf`